# Tableview and Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, ios5

I am developing an iOS App that is bank passbook type. I have a problem when I insert a record in the database, it should be arranged in chronological order according to date as below.

Suppose I withdraw from ATM $20 and date is 12/20/11 now total balance is $200.

```
  *date*               *amount*        *type*      *balance*     *counter*
  12/20/11              $20             ATM          $200         1
  12/21/11              $30             Deposit      $230         2
  12/23/11              $30             ATM          $200         3
  10/01/11              $100            ATM          $100         4
```

Now it should be show in table View as well as update in sqlite database. As this:

```
  *date*               *amount*        *type*      *balance*     *counter*
  10/01/11              $100            ATM          $120          1
  12/20/11              $20             ATM          $100          2
  12/21/11              $30             Deposit      $130          3
  12/23/11              $30             ATM          $100          4
```

As I mentioned above before 12/20/11 balance was $220. There will be any number of transactions. Please let me know how it can be solved. I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: You need more detail than this:  are you using Core Data?  are you using bindings?  If not, can you add code to this question to show how you are doing "cellForRowAtIndexPath" (i.e. displaying the data in the table view)?

Comment: No I am using Sqlite I want that these type of table is maintain inside database then I will arrange in Tableview..When I insert any record then it should check that which date is come first and arrange as in table-2...Or have you any idea to show in table view because I am not able to think logic for this..please if it is possible help me.@MichaelDautermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "Order by" in sql query

for more information 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: My problem is that normally any record is inserted in database added in last row but i want to add it middle according to date where it fit..thanks for reply

Comment: @borrrden so what i have to do to solve yhis problem have u any idea

Comment: Use order by like this answer says

Comment: the order of insertion in database is irrelevant... your query tells in which order it should output.